# jQuery animate one div at a time

Tags: jquery

I have some tab style divs that currently sit behind a footer div. When the tops of these tabs are clicked, they slide up. However I want to know how to only have **one** slide up—so when you click tab a then tab b, tab a will slide back down as tab b is now active.

Currently they slide up on click, but I couldn't work out how to make only one able to be visible at any one time. Alternatively it would be useful if you could click to close as well, although I left this out as I wasn't sure how to make thing work alongside everything else I'm trying to do.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="some__content">
    <h1>some content</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
            <div class="tab__menu">

                <div class="tab--hobbit tab--left">
                    <a href="#" class="tab--header">
                        <h3>Why choose us?</h3>
                    </a>
                    <div class="tab--content">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin nec neque ligula. Nulla rutrum...</p>
                        <a href="" class="btn btn--med btn--soft">Learn More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="tab--hobbit tab--middle">
                    <a href="#" class="tab--header">
                        <h3>Why choose us?</h3>
                    </a>
                    <div class="tab--content">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin nec neque ligula. Nulla rutrum...</p>
                        <a href="" class="btn btn--med btn--soft">Learn More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="tab--hobbit tab--right">
                    <a href="#" class="tab--header">
                        <h3>Why choose us?</h3>
                    </a>
                    <div class="tab--content">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin nec neque ligula. Nulla rutrum...</p>
                        <a href="" class="btn btn--med btn--soft">Learn More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div> <!-- /*** end menu -->
        </div>

        <div class="quote__slider">
            <h2>fdgdfgdfgfdgdg</h2>
        </div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var tabItem = $(".tab--hobbit");

    function closeTab(){
        tabItem.removeClass("active");
    }

    tabItem.click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        closeTab();
        $(this).addClass("active");

        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).animate({
                top: -168
            });
        } else if (!tabItem.hasClass('active')) {
            closeTab();
            $(tabItem).animate({
                top: 0
            });
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(this).toggleClass("active");

if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    $(this).animate({
        top: -80
    });
} else {
    $(this).animate({
        top: 0
    });
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vg55B/)

Comment: This does not help me set the top position of non-active tabs back to ```0```